# How to connect Node.js server app to SQL Server (with 'mssql') when hosting on Azure App Service?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

For several months I'm working on Node.js express app that connects to SQL Server (2016) successfully and run queries smoothly.

I got the app ready after the connection configuration to the DB, deployment and hosting on apache2, and a React client app that send requests to the Node.js server and retrieve data with queries from the SQL Server.

There is a need to host the app with Azure, I followed the documentations on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode, To deploy my Node.js server app and skipped "Create your Node.js application", The deployment succeeded and with Postman I got proper responds from the domain Azure gave me(from routes that don't query the DB).

But I got error in the Log Stream:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to XX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXX in 15000ms.

If I work locally or with Apache domain there is no error with connection establishment.

What adjustment I need to make to the Node.js app/Azure/SQL Server to fix it?

Here is my Node.js app:

`mssql.js` as I got it:

```
var sql = require("mssql");
require("dotenv").config();

const config = {
  user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  server: process.env.DB_SERVER,
  port: JSON.parse(process.env.DB_PORT),
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  requestTimeout: 3600000, //an hour
  options: {
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    encrypt: true,
  },
  debug: true,
  parseJSON: true,
};

let pool;

const initConnect = async () => {
  try {
    const pool = await sql.connect(config);
    return pool;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    console.log("Error connecting to DB...", err);
    sql.close();
  }
};

const initMod = async () => {
  this.pool = await initConnect();
  console.log("open connecion...");
};

initMod();

module.exports.pool = pool;
module.exports.SQLInst = sql;
```

And this is the server.js file:
(I also see in the logs that sql.pool is undefined when request /getItems of course)

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const sql = require("./mssql");

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome to test server!");
});

//  Getting items from db
app.get("/getItems", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Getting items...`);
  try {
    const data = await sql.pool.request().query("SELECT * FROM PartsPics");
    const items = await data.recordset;
    res.status(200).send(items);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Error occured: ", e);
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});
```

I tried several solutions that I saw on the config object but it didn't fix the error.

I make sure that in the SQL Server Configuration Manager start mode is set to automatic and TCP/IP is enabled.

Comment: Aside... Use `user` and `password` together, or use `options.trustedConnection: true`. The latter attempts to use Windows Authentication instead of SQL Login authentication.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks for the clarifications, I omitted `options.trustedConnection: true` , The authentication method is indeed SQL Server Authentication. The error is the same though...